# Noise analyses of an op-amp circuit analysis using Kirchhoff's current law

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, noise

I am trying to understand this example from Sergio Franco *Design with Operational Amplifiers and Analog Integrated Circuits* about how to analyse the overall spectral density.

He writes that, by using superposition for the noise current i_R1 we have that the contribution is (i_R1 *  R1||R2).

When I try to do the same by making KCL around X we have that i_R1+i_1 +i_2 = 0 and because i_1 = (0-x)/R1, i_2 = (E_no-x)/R_2 and x = 0V.

Then i_R1 = E_no/R2 so the contribution is i_R1 * R2 and not i_R1*R1||R2.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i_R1 * R2 is the output noise i.e., E_no.

i_R1*R1||R2 is the input referred noise i.e., in figure 7.9 (b), what value of **en** will make the output i_R1 * R2

We know that the output with an input of en on the non-inverting terminal is **en * (1 + R2/R1)**.
Now, **equate en * (1 + R2/R1) = i_R1 * R2**
So, **en = i_R1*R1||R2**